# Redux state not showing correctly in method after first render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I've implemented an error handling scenario whereby an `error` state updates to `true` or `false` depending on the result of an API call. I don't think I need to post my full action and reducer files, as they are working fine. I'll simply describe the behavior that is going on.

In the file that is causing me issues, call it `mainComponent.js`, I've got something like this:

```
const mainComponent = () => {
  const error = useSelector(state => state.myStore.error)

  console.log("error from within component", error)

  const handlingErrorChange = () => {
    console.log("error from within handlingErrorChange", error)
    if (error === false) {
      <Snackbar 
        ancorOrigin{{vertical: "top"}}
        autoHideDuration={2000}
      > 
        Messaged saved successfully
      </Snackbar>
    } else {
      <Snackbar 
        ancorOrigin{{vertical: "top"}}
        autoHideDuration={2000}
      > 
        There was an error. Please try saving again.
      </Snackbar>
    }
  }
}
```

The `error` state from the store is being updated correctly from `console.log("error from within component", error)` line. For example, if the API call results in an error, that line shows `error` as true.

However, in the same scenario, `console.log("error from within handlingErrorChange", error)` still displays error as false, and it is only on the next render that the state variable from within the `handlingErrorChange` that it updates correctly to true.

Is this normal behavior? If so, what do I need to do in order for the `error` redux state to update correctly on the first render as it is doing from within `mainComponent`? I don't think it is a console log problem as I am doing an assertion based on whether `error` is true or false in the `handlingErrorChange` method and the behavior is still incorrect.

I’ve seen online that one can use ‘mapstatetoprops’ but I prefer to use ‘useSelector’ instead. Surely if this is normal behavior, there must be a solution! It doesn’t seem to be a very uncommon scenario to have.

**EDIT**

Please help! I’ve been stuck on this for two days and it’s driving me insane.

Comment: Yes, the behavior is correct. Redux queues it for the next render. I'm confused about your behavior, do you want to render something if there is an error?

Comment: How are you using `handlingErrorChange`? And what else is that function doing?

Comment: So in essence, I am rendering a snackbar message using Material UI's `Snackbar` component depending on whether there was an error or not. That's pretty much the jist of that method. What is the best thing to do in that case to ensure I have the correct `error` value?

Comment: if I am correct about your implementation, can you do return error && <Snackbar/>

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've got an `if` condition anyway so it's something similar: if(error === false) // do something, else //do something else

Comment: What I'm still confused about is why `error` is correct outside the method but not within (in the same component).

Comment: I tried to create a simplified example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/reactredux-forked-4ynjz?file=/Page.js. As you can see, everything seems to work properly and the value of `error` is aligned inside and outside the function, regardless of whether you set it with the `useSelector()` hook or with your `useError()` custom hook.