# Custom hook not updating in function within component until second render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68458331/redux-state-not-showing-correctly-in-method-after-first-render) whereby I am simply trying to retrieve an error state from my redux store and have it render in a nested function within a component on the first render. Right now, it only updates on the second render.

I have therefore tried to go around this issue and create a custom hook, which retrieves the error state from the store, and then use it accordingly. These are my files so far:

**useError.js**

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux"

export const useError = () => {
  const error = useSelector(state => state.error)

  return error
}
```

I am then trying to use this in my mainComponent:

**MainComponent.js**

```
const MainComponent = () => {
  const error = useError()
  console.log(error) // This shows the correctly updated error state
    
  const nestedMethod = () => {
    console.log(error) // This shows an older version of the state on the first render, and only correctly updates on the second render
    if (error === false) {
      <Snackbar 
        ancorOrigin{{vertical: "top"}}
        autoHideDuration={2000}
      > 
        Messaged saved successfully
      </Snackbar>
    } else {
      <Snackbar 
        ancorOrigin{{vertical: "top"}}
        autoHideDuration={2000}
      > 
        There was an error. Please try saving again.
      </Snackbar>
    }
  }
}
```

I am very confused by this concept of useSelector() and it only updating correctly in nested methods on the next render cycle. For me, this nullifies the whole point of Redux because you're not then using a real-time view of the state.

In any case, why is this same behavior happening when I use a custom hook?

**EDIT**

Updated `nestedMethod` to loosely show it's functionality. The problem is that even when `error === true`, the first render shows a success message and it only displays the error message on the second render cycle.

Comment: Can you show us how do you use `nestedMethod`?

Comment: @MarcoNisi I have edited my question. In essence, I just display a message using Material UI's `Snackbar` whether there was an error or not.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you created a custom hook rather than using `const error = useSelector(state => state.error)` directly in `MainComponent`?

Comment: @secan it's only because with that way, I couldn't get it to work. Could you please see my previous question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68458331/redux-state-not-showing-correctly-in-method-after-first-render

Comment: @Adam are you using `nestedMethod` inside some `useCallback` or other hooks?

Comment: @MarcoNisi I am not.

Comment: Without see the whole component is hard to understand what it's wrong.

Comment: There is other functionality within the component that is true, but the main point is that the state doesn't update on the first render cycle. I have even tried the same on another component and inside a nested method, but the behavior still is the same.

Comment: Silly question: are you 100% sure that `error` is *always* either `true` or `false` and not any other "truthy" or "falsy" value (e.g. `null` or `undefined`)?

Comment: @Adam ok, if the outer `console.log` prints the correct state but in the `nestedMethod` prints the wrong state, it seems to be that there are some errors in other parts of the component/project. Can you try to call the `nestedMethod` just after the outer `console.log` and tell us what prints out?

Comment: @secan yes, the initial state in the store for `error` is `false` and it's only set between `false` and `true` so I'm pretty sure it can only be one of those two values.

Comment: @MarcoNisi sure, I will try that and report back.

Comment: @MarcoNisi so if I call `nestedMethod` directly after the outer `console.log`, it gives me the correct value.  The thing is, I'm calling `nestedMethod` from another nested method and when I do that, the value doesn't get updated on the first cycle. Is that then expected?

Comment: @Adam when and where the other nested method is called? Is inside some hook (useEffect, useCallback, custom hooks etc..)?

Comment: @Adam I'm pretty sure you're looking at the wrong thing. The problem is not `nestedMethod()` but likely the time when you call it. Please show the complete component, preferably in a sandbox.

Comment: @hendra yes I agree

Comment: I tried to create a simplified example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/reactredux-forked-4ynjz?file=/Page.js. As you can see, everything seems to work properly and the value of `error` is aligned inside and outside the function, regardless of whether you set it with the `useSelector()` hook or with your `useError()` custom hook.

Comment: [In the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68458331/redux-state-not-showing-correctly-in-method-after-first-render) you mentioned the value of `error` comes from an API; is it possible you are trying to dispatch the action that sets `state.error` before you receive the API response?

Comment: @secan thank you for creating the simplified example! I'll take a look and see where my changes are different. With regards to my other question, I only dispatch setting the error (as you've done in your example) once the response from the API is received. So I don't believe it would set it before the API response.